# still finding system python with pyenv installed - installing modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pyenv

On Mac, current OS, system python is still 2.7. I've installed pyenv, and successfully installed 3.7.3.

```
dandonaldson@Dans-MacBook-Pro-2 gpt-2 % pyenv local
3.7.3
dandonaldson@Dans-MacBook-Pro-2 gpt-2 % pyenv global
3.7.3
dandonaldson@Dans-MacBook-Pro-2 gpt-2 %
```

If I now I try to install pipx, as a way to install packages, I get

```
dandonaldson@Dans-MacBook-Pro-2 gpt-2 % pip install --user pipx 
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting pipx
  Using cached pipx-0.15.4.0.tar.gz (336 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/fz/hkppw37x1tz20d3jv8rb3vmr0000gn/T/pip-install-u0WjuX/pipx/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/fz/hkppw37x1tz20d3jv8rb3vmr0000gn/T/pip-install-u0WjuX/pipx/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/fz/hkppw37x1tz20d3jv8rb3vmr0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-bKDh7q
         cwd: /private/var/folders/fz/hkppw37x1tz20d3jv8rb3vmr0000gn/T/pip-install-u0WjuX/pipx/
    Complete output (1 lines):
    Python 3.6 or later is required. See https://github.com/pipxproject/pipx for installation instructions.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I'm told not to remove the python in */Frameworks, so it seems like I have to get around this while leaving that in place.

A previous shot using brew left me with

```
    which python
    python: aliased to /usr/local/bin/python3.8

and when I try this I get

brew uninstall python
Error: Refusing to uninstall /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.4
because it is required by imagemagick, which is currently installed.
You can override this and force removal with:
  brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python
```

So,...

- can I uninstall the brew python without the world ending? I have no python projects
- how can I get module packages to install by default in a place accessible to 3.7.3?

I've used rubyenv for many years, it's not this wretched…  :(

Extra points: does Python and pyenv have the same behaviour of allowing python environments to have their own modules and versions?

Answer (score 6):

Let me try this again:

## Question 1

> - can I uninstall the brew python without the world ending? I have no python projects

I am afraid not, as `imagemagick` is currently using it -- which means every binary that requires `imagemagick` requires `python3`.

## Question 2

> - how can I get module packages to install by default in a place accessible to 3.7.3?

**From what I understand, what you are trying to say more broadly is: "How can I install packages with the `pip` binary relative to the Python version I have installed with `pyenv`?".**

**The answer should be: `pyenv` should take care of it. If it does not, you should do an additional step.** Please keep in mind I will assume you have installed `pyenv` with `homebrew`.

### 1. How to [check if `pyenv` works](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#how-to-verify-that-i-have-set-up-pyenv-correctly)

If `pyenv` was set up correctly, the following line will be the output of the command `echo $PATH`:

```
$(pyenv root)/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

where `$(pyenv root)` is the place where pyenv is located - which most of the time is `~/.pyenv`. But you can change it by setting `PYENV_ROOT` in your `~/.zshenv` (I like to have these things in `~/.config/` to clear the clutter in my `~/` directory).

The official documentation suggests to run `echo $PATH | grep --color=auto "$(pyenv root)/shims"`. If there is no output or it's an error (e.g., `echo $?` returns the error `1`), then one additional step is required.

### 2. The additional step to set up `pyenv` after installation with `homebrew`

Run the following command in your terminal emulator:

```
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init --path)"' >> ~/.zprofile
```

(alternatively, if you have set up your `ZDOTDIR` environmental variable, run `echo 'eval "$(pyenv init --path)"' >> $ZDOTDIR/.zprofile`).

Then restart your shell. Now your path should look the way you expect it to.

### 3. Additional step to enable `pyenv` commands autocompletion

Run the following command to enable tab-completion in the terminal for `pyenv` commands.

```sh
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc # or $ZDOTDIR/.zshrc
```

### 4. Is `pyenv` working?

You can check again by looking at your `$PATH` variable:

```sh
$ echo $PATH | tr ":" "\\n" # to have it spit out in an orderly fashion
/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/condabin # don't mind this
/Users/luca/.local/bin # these are my custom scripts
/Users/luca/.pyenv/shims # this is what you are looking for!
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Library/TeX/texbin
/opt/X11/bin
```

Do **not** mind the `/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/condabin` portion, I am mainly using `conda` to manage Python environments.

Then, if you run `which/where pip` or `which/where pip3` to see which binaries it is actually using when you are attempting to install a package, you should see:

```sh
$ where pip3
/Users/luca/.pyenv/shims/pip3 # that's pyenv
/usr/local/bin/pip3 # this is homebrew
/usr/bin/pip3 # this is the systems'

$ where pip
/Users/luca/.pyenv/shims/pip # that's pyenv
```

This indicates that when you execute a command with `pip` or `pip3` the binary installed with `pyenv` will be used and the global or local version of Python will be actually working under the hood.

### An example

I installed Python `3.9.5` with `pyenv` and set it as a global version, then used it to install `pandas`:

```sh
$ pip install pandas
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-1.2.4-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (10.7 MB)
Collecting numpy>=1.16.5
  Downloading numpy-1.20.3-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (16.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 16.1 MB 1.8 MB/s
Collecting pytz>=2017.3
  Using cached pytz-2021.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.7.3
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
Collecting six>=1.5
  Downloading six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Installing collected packages: six, pytz, python-dateutil, numpy, pandas
Successfully installed numpy-1.20.3 pandas-1.2.4 python-dateutil-2.8.1 pytz-2021.1 six-1.16.0
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.1; however, version 21.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Users/luca/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/bin/python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

This does not seem helpful but please note that in the `WARNING` it says `/Users/luca/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/bin/python3.9`, which indicates I am indeed using `pyenv`'s Python.

## Question 3

> Extra points: does Python and pyenv have the same behaviour of allowing python environments to have their own modules and versions?

Yes! Several options for environments can be used. `conda` is the most used, then someone uses `pyenv-virtualenv` or other provided officially by Python (it should be [`pipenv`](https://realpython.com/pipenv-guide/). I have always used `conda`, but it does not offer any official auto-completion and sometimes is annoying. There are other alternatives, such as [`mamba`](https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba) - never used it tho.